# C# Dictionary.Add is forgotten when it gets out of the loop

Tags: c#, linq

I wonder why `Amounts.Add` below does not affect `ixs`

```
  private class ItemExtra
  {
    public int Id;
    public Dictionary<int, int> Amounts = new Dictionary<int, int>();
  }

  ...

  var ixs = (new[] { 10, 11 }).Select(x => new ItemExtra { Id = x });
  foreach (ItemExtra ix in ixs)
  {
    ix.Amounts.Add(1, 1); // This is forgotten when it gets out of the loop
    if(ix.Id == 11)
      ix.Amounts.Add(2, 1); // This is forgotten when it gets out of the loop
  }

  // Test if Amounts have been added
  foreach(ItemExtra ix in ixs)
    Response.Write(ix.Id + ": " + ix.Amounts.Count + "<br>");
```

Expected output

```
10: 1
11: 2
```

What I got

```
10: 0
11: 0
```

Why does that happen? How do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe becausre the `IEnumerable` `inx` has not been evaluated as a collection, try adding `.ToList()` e.g. `var ixs = (new[] { 10, 11 }).Select(x => new ItemExtra { Id = x }).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because LINQ is lazy and execution is deferred. You're `ixs` is just a query deifinition, so every time you start enumerating it, you're getting new collection, with new `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instances.

Add `ToList()` or `ToArray()` call to get the collection instead of a query definition.

```
var ixs = (new[] { 10, 11 }).Select(x => new ItemExtra { Id = x }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because of deferred execution, note that `ixs` is just a query in your case. You can try using `ToList` like this:

```
var ixs = (new[] { 10, 11 }).Select(x => new ItemExtra { Id = x }).ToList();
```

Without using something like `ToList()`, each time executing the query `ixs`, the `new ItemExtra` will be created for each element, that's why any changes you made in the first loop won't affect anything.

Answer (score 1):

The `IEnumerable<ItemExtra>` it will be evaluated every time you iterate over it. and since objects are created in the `Query` it will return new objects each time and the orginal items will not be updated.

If you materialize the query first e.g. by adding `ToList()` then it should work

Answer (score 1):

Try using toarray to get list object before you update it. I think you work on a linq query object without this and it probably is returning a new object every time you try to iterate it.

```
var ixs = (new[] { 10, 11 }).Select(x => new ItemExtra { Id = x }).ToArray();
```